# Как корректно преобразовать строку в массив?

Tags: php, c#

ps Перевожу c# код в php.

Есть строка `c1967eecc1ca477292d7f085c0a5987a`. Эту строку надо перевести в массив.

```
$value = 'c1967eecc1ca477292d7f085c0a5987a';
foreach (str_split($value2) as $chr) {
     $hex_ary[] = sprintf("%02X", ord($chr));
}
$res = implode(' ',$hex_ary);
```

На выходе должно получиться

```
193
150
126
236
193
202
71  
114
146
215
240
133
192
165
152
122
```

Но у меня получаются вообще другие числа. Предполагаю что ошибка кроется где то в `sprintf`

Этот массив я могу с помощью c# кода привести к исходному виду.

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
       StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
       foreach (byte b in ba)
          hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
       return hex.ToString();
    }
    #c1967eecc1ca477292d7f085c0a5987a
```

Подскажите что в моем php-коде некорректно?

Comment: Почему из "с" должно получиться 193? почему одинаковые символы имеют разные коды?

Comment: @Ипатьев из `c1` а не из `c`. в шарпе на входе массив байт, а в пхп его строковое представление

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нечто подобное ищите?

```
$value = "c1967eecc1ca477292d7f085c0a5987a";
$result = unpack("C*", hex2bin($value)),

print_r($result);
```

проблема вашего кода в том, что вы берете строковое представление байт-массива, и разбиваете его посимвольно, хотя в таком случае разделят надо по 2 символа, ибо байт это значения `00-FF` а не `0-F`, да и `ord($c)` потом дает ASCII-код символа, а не переведенное hex-значение

кстати, я так понимаю вашу C# функцию можно просто заменить на вызов

```
BitConverter.ToString(ba);
```

Answer (score 1):

Парсим по 2 символа

```
var str = "c1967eecc1ca477292d7f085c0a5987a";
for(int i=0; i<str.Length; i+=2)        
    Console.WriteLine(byte.Parse(str.Substring(i,2), 
        System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

Получаем на выходе

```
193
150
126
236
193
202
71
114
146
215
240
133
192
165
152
122
```

Comment: проблема то в пхп коде, а не в c#

Comment: @teran это типично для меня, читать вопросы по диагонали, не обращайте внимание :)