# BitConverter.ToUInt32 в php?

Tags: php, c#

Есть в `c#` метод `BitConverter.ToUInt32`. Какой аналог у него в `php`? Просмотрел весь `SO` - не нашёл ответ

```
byte[] hash = MakeHash(value);
uint k = BitConverter.ToUInt32(hash, hash.Length - _signLen);
```

Делаю так, но на выходе null почему-то

```
$hash = $this->MakeHash($value);
$res = unpack("L", $hash,8);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190335/converting-binary-packing-c-sharp-code-to-php

Comment: `unpack("L", $value, $offset)`, [вчера же с вами распаковывали в массив байт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/992384/223826). логично,вроде, что  распаковка в другие типы будет аналогично работать

Comment: @teran когда я делаю `unpack("L", $hash,8)` на выходе у меня null

Comment: а чего там у вас в `$hash`? что-то мне кажется, там у вас строка.

Comment: @teran `$hash = {array} [16]
 1 = {int} 102
 2 = {int} 41
 3 = {int} 156
 4 = {int} 64
 5 = {int} 54
 6 = {int} 101
 7 = {int} 223
 8 = {int} 38
 9 = {int} 209
 10 = {int} 47
 11 = {int} 90
 12 = {int} 173
 13 = {int} 60
 14 = {int} 141
 15 = {int} 126
 16 = {int} 108`

Comment: @teran https://pastebin.com/wY3k3WCV

Comment: @teran на выходе должно получиться число `2908368849`

Comment: @teran что скажете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас `$hash` это массив байт, хотя `unpack` ожидает на входе бинарную строку.
Можно сначала упаковать в бинарную строку, потом извлечь целые (для старых версих пхп, где параметра `offset` нет:

```
$hash = [102,41,156,64,54,101,223,38,209,47,90,173,60,141,126,108];
$bin = pack("C*", ...$hash);

echo bin2hex($bin) . "\n" ;
$k = unpack("L*", $bin);
print_r($k);
```

получите

```
66299c403665df26d12f5aad3c8d7e6c
Array
(
    [1] => 1083976038
    [2] => 652174646
    [3] => 2908368849
    [4] => 1820233020
)
```

То ест искомое значение будет третьим в массиве. В пхп 7.1 можно сразу сделать

```
$k = unpack("L", $bin , 8);
```

В целом нет смысла упаковывать весь массив, если нам нужны только 4 байта из него, то их и надо сначала извлечь, а потом сформировать int.

```
 $offset = 8;
 $data = array_slice($hash, $offset, 4);
 $tmp = pack("C*", ...$data);
 $k = unpack("L", $tmp);
```

В целом чтобы из 4х байт составить двойное слово никакие `pack/unpack`, конечно, не нужны. достаточно расставить байты на свои места, используя битовые сдвиги:

```
$offset = 8;
$b = array_slice($hash, $offset, 4);
$k = ($b[0] << 0) +
     ($b[1] << 8) +
     ($b[2] << 16)+
     ($b[3] << 24);
```